# Is there an implementation of the geodesic voronoi diagram in a simple polygon usable from Python?

Tags: python, path, diagram, voronoi, shortest

As the title states, I am trying to find an implementation of the geodesic voronoi diagram in a simple polygon. Ideally it would be usable from Python. It is sometimes referred to as the shortest path voronoi diagram.

It is the voronoi diagram of points contained within a non-convex bounding polygon where the shortest paths determining the voronoi cells are constrained to be within the polygon. Note this is not the same as simply clipping a standard voronoi diagram with a bounding polygon, - the cells are generated within a 2D polygon.

This is a simple illustration of a standard voronoi diagram clipped to a bounding polygon:

[image]

And this is a simple illustration of the geodesic voronoi diaram generated within the polygon:

[image]

I have come across four papers that describe this and some algorithms to achieve it:

- [Aronov, B. (1987). On the geodesic Voronoi diagram of point sites in a simple polygon.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/41958.41963)
- [Guth, N. and Klingel, P. (2012). Demand Allocation in Water Distribution Network Modelling – A GIS-Based Approach Using Voronoi Diagrams with Constraints.](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/40534)
- [Liu, C.-H. (2019). A Nearly Optimal Algorithm for the Geodesic Voronoi Diagram of Points in a Simple Polygon.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1007/s00453-019-00624-2)
- [Oh, E. (2019). Optimal Algorithm for Geodesic Nearest-point Voronoi diagrams in Simple Polygons.](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611975482.25)

I have also found a video that describes it where the points are also moving within the polygon:

- [Kinetic Geodesic Voronoi Diagrams in a Simple Polygon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qyh1_B4aRRs)

Ideally any implementation would be usable from Python but any implementations at all would be appreciated to start with.

Many thanks.